# How to animate visibility in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want an imported object in Three.js to appear slowly. I have already searched for answers, but I have still no idea.

To show and hide is working well with this code:

```
function spielfunktion_01_einblenden() {
    Objekt_Spielfunktion_02 = scene.getObjectByName("Neo02_02");
    Objekt_Spielfunktion_01.traverse(function (child) {
        child.visible = true;
    });
}
```

**Well: How can I get a transition effect to make objects visible?**

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You can use Tween.js for `opacity` of an object's material.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, you have a cube in your scene (our abstract object which we want to apply our transition to):

```
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: "red",
  transparent: true,
  opacity: 0
}));
```

and two buttons with onclick events for making our cube visible or invisible with transition of opacity (their IDs are `showOn` and `showOff`):

```
showOn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  cube.visible = true;
  var tweenon = new TWEEN.Tween(cube.material).to({
    opacity: 1
  }, 2000).
  onComplete(function(){
    cube.material.transparent = false;
  });
  tweenon.start();
});

showOff.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  cube.material.transparent = true;
  var tweenoff = new TWEEN.Tween(cube.material).to({
    opacity: 0
  }, 2000).
  onComplete(function(){
    cube.visible = false;
  });
  tweenoff.start();
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/15b9p5dg/) example.

Comment: @cyra Mark the answer as accepted, if it solves your question.

Answer (score 0):

You mean like a transparency? try opacity attribute on your Mesh and add it to ur scene.

```
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff, opacity: 1.0 } ));
scene.add( cube );
```